# How can calculate the geometry's file size

Tags: blend-files

I want to display geometry's effect on file size. How can calculate geometry and animation data file size ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this sort of functionality exists in Blender, because even when you append models from another file and that's done using Blender's file browser that has "size" tab in detailed view that has no info about size of Blender's datablocks. https://i.postimg.cc/kMcywxj6/image.png

Comment: Should I take geometry file size from .bin file after animation deleted if it is existing? I need some tips for 'animation data size' and 'geometry data size'

Comment: Blender's status bar shows what seems to be file size in RAM, but that does not correspond with saved file sizes at all and also fluctuates unpredictably(at least to me) so I don't really know... Maybe try asking about this on [devtalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/) forums.  Have a look at [Memory Statistics operator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/operators.html?highlight=data%20size%20memory#memory-statistics) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much I created new topic in devtalk : https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-do-i-calculate-the-geometrys-file-size/25589